# How to enable USB Storage for Amazon Kindle Fire HD 7" Tablet

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, amazon-kindle-fire, usb-storage, wiki

I have these **Amazon Kindle Fire HD 7" Tablet**, ever since I bought it and the first time it prompted me if I wanna enable **USB mass storage** when I connected it to the computer, and I selected **charge only** or something close to that, up to this very moment, I can't access the tablet from a computer via **USB cable**

```
Specifications;

Android version: Android-5.1.1
Device Model: KFFOWI
```

Any solution please?

Answer (score 1):

There are USB options which control how the port is to be used (or not) when connected to a computer.  Unfortunately, these options are pretty well hidden -- the easiest way to get to them is if you get a notification about the USB, and can click on it to open the USB options.
Otherwise, to get to the options:

- From the top, pull down the toolbar and select the options (gear icon).
- In the Device section, you have Device Options, open that.
- There is a hidden "Developer Options" here (OS 5.6.8, but may be up a level under "Device Options" -- unhide by tapping the "Serial Number" name seven (7) times (you might get a countdown).  Then the Developer Options should be unhidden, either right below the Serial Number, or up a level under Device Options.
- Open the "Developer Options and tap on "USB Connections" selection.
- You get choices on how the USB connection is used, select File transfer, or MTP (Media Transfer Protocol), or PTP (picture transfer Protocol),...

Answer (score 0):

You might need to re install necessary drivers for your device. Alternatively try using [USB Mass storage enabler](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JYGD2EW), from Amazon marketplace